# How to use shared module in all components in angular 4?

Tags: module, export, components, angular4-router

I'm using `Angular 4` with `material`. And I have main two components...

`1) Login and 2) Dashboard`

There are lazy loading components in `dashboard` like `profile` , `employee` etc...
I want to set `header` and for that I have used `<mat-toolbar>`

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>My application</span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>

    <button mat-button>Logout</button>
  </mat-toolbar-row>  
</mat-toolbar>
```

and component file is this .

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {
 }
}
```

To use this component in all `dashboard` I have create one `shared module` file.

In `src/app/shared/modules/header/header.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HeaderComponent } from 
     '../../../shared/components/header/header.component';
import { MaterialModule } from '../../../material.module';
@NgModule({
imports: [
  CommonModule,
  MaterialModule      
],
declarations: [HeaderComponent],
exports:[HeaderComponent]
})
export class HeaderModule { }
```

I have `import` component in module file and put in `exports` so, I think I'm able to use `header` component.

Now I'm trying to use it in `dashboard` component.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard-routing.module';
import { MaterialModule } from '../material.module';
import { HeaderModule } from '../shared/modules/header/header.module';

@NgModule({
imports: [
  CommonModule,
  DashboardRoutingModule,
  MaterialModule,
  HeaderModule    
],
declarations: [DashboardComponent]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

I have also import `module` and set `header component` in `entryComponetnt` in  `app.module.ts` file also...

app.module.ts

```
import { HeaderModule } from './shared/modules/header/header.module';
imports: [
 FormsModule,       
 HeaderModule
],
entryComponents:[HeaderComponent]
```

The issue is I'm getting header when I go `dashboard` page. And also I'm not getting any error in `console`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just add my shared component's `selector` value in dashboard's html file.

`<app-header></app-header>`

It works for me!